# How to assign more than one Collection in a ObservableCollection using Inline C# Statement?

Tags: c#, inline, observablecollection

I'm having a Collection of a Model

```
public class MobileModelInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Catagory { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Here I need to assign Morethan ONE collection within a `new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>()` using single statement without using `mobList.Add()` as like following statement

```
ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> mobList = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(
    (new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" }),
    (new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" }),
    (new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" })
);
```

But it generates the Compile time error, kindly assist me to achieve this via Inline Statement.

> Note: Don't suggest `mobList.Add()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `ObservableCollection` accepts as parameters either a `List<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` or nothing.

You forgot to declare a list before adding the items. Try it like this:

```
ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> mobList = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(new List<MobileModelInfo>(){
    new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" },
    new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" },
    new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" }
});
```

Comment: I given you one Up Vote. So, I need to wait 5 mins then only I can mark it as Answer.